# Trouble with WebSockets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, dart-async

I am having some trouble implementing WebSockets in my flutter application.

Here is code my code:

```
void connectToWebSocket() {
print("trying to connect to websocket");

final Future futureChannel = establishConnection();
futureChannel.then((future) {
  print("Connection established, registering interest now...");
  channel = future;
  webSocketConnected = true;
  channel.sink.add({
    "action": "saveConnection",
    "UserName": "rakshak@gmail.com",
    "DeviceId": "1d0032000947363339343638"
  });
}).catchError((error) {
  channel = null;
  webSocketConnected = false;
  webSocketConnectionError = error.toString();
  print("Connection failed \n $webSocketConnectionError");
});
}

Future<IOWebSocketChannel> establishConnection() async {
final IOWebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    'wss://1j839fy6t3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Dev');

return channel;
}
```

Nothing seems to happen when this code runs. I can see the print messages saying "trying to connect to WebSocket" and "Connection established, registering interest now..." on the console.

The WebSocket is implemented using AWS API Gateway and I can see in the logs that the Flutter app has not connected to the WebSocket.

I have tested the WebSocket using `wscat` command-line tool and I know that it works.

[image: wscat command line tool]

I am not seeing any error in the console.

Let me know if you would like to see any more of my code.

Comment: Did you provide some authentication with wscat?

Comment: Nope. Trying out WebSockets for the first time, so implementing it plain for now.
I've added a screenshot of the wscat test.

Comment: hey @DrkStr did y managed to connect to AWS websockets?

Comment: hey @DrkStr nice! I am struglling figureing out how to connect  the aws-iot with flutter, could you help me? Here you have my e-mail simemap@simemap.com

Comment: I don't have any experience with AWS IoT. I just used the WebSockets in API gateway. Happy to help you with that. :)

Comment: @DrkStr do you mind sharing the snippet of what exactly you changed on the code for it to work for you? I am having the same issue :(

Comment: @Nazehs hey, I've posted an answer with what worked for me. Sorry I didn't post it earlier, I was too pissed off with this whole thing at the time. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you `channel.sink.add` accepts a string and not a Map.

Replace

```
channel.sink.add({
"action": "saveConnection",
"UserName": "rakshak@gmail.com",
"DeviceId": "1d0032000947363339343638"
});
```

With

```
channel.sink.add('{
"action": "saveConnection",
"UserName": "rakshak@gmail.com",
"DeviceId": "1d0032000947363339343638"
}');
```

and it should work.

Comment: ```
channel.sink.add(jsonEncode({
"action": "saveConnection",
"UserName": "rakshak@gmail.com",
"DeviceId": "1d0032000947363339343638"
}));
```

was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want. But If you want websocket, you can refer below one.

1. Add Dart Pub

   ```
   adhara_socket_io
   ```
2. Add class

   ```
   class SignalServer {
    static SignalServer _instatnce;
    factory SignalServer() => _instatnce ?? new SignalServer._();
    SignalServer._();
    SocketIO socketIO;
    int State = 0;
    void ConnectServer() async {
      this.socketIO = await SocketIOManager().createInstance("http://192.168.50.65:8081");
      socketIO.onConnect((data) {
       print("Signal server connected");
       State = 1;
      });
      socketIO.onDisconnect((_) {
       print("Signal Disconnected");
       State = 0;
      });
      socketIO.connect();
    }
   }
   ```
3. For Instance(main.dart)

   ```
   static SignalServer signalServer;
   ....
   signalServer = new SignalServer();
   signalServer.ConnectServer();
   ```
4. For use

In any widget

```
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  setSocketEvent();
 }
 void setSocketEvent() async{
   await MyApp.signalServer.socketIO.on("room-ready", (data) {
     //enter your code
   });
   await MyApp.signalServer.socketIO.on("on-message", (data) {
     //enter your code
   });
   ...
 }
```

I hope it will help you.